# Creating subplots with a pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, plot, pivot, multi-index

Given the dataframe below I want to create a figure with two subplots, one for each Hemisphere. Plts should show means against diffs.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                   'eye':['l','r','l','r','l','r','l','r'],
                   'trial':[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2],
                   'S':[2,2,3,3,5,5,7,7],
                   'I':[2,2,1,1,4,4,3,3]})

df = df.melt(id_vars=['id','eye','trial'],
             value_vars=['S','I'],
             var_name='Hemisphere',
             value_name='Thickness')

df = df.pivot_table(index=['id','eye','Hemisphere'],
                    columns='trial',
                    values='Thickness')

df['diffs'] = df[1] - df[2]
df['means'] = np.mean([df[1], df[2]], axis=0)

df = df.unstack(level=2)

df.plot('means','diffs',subplots=True,kind='scatter')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `groupby` with `axis=1`

```
axes = df[['diffs', 'means']].groupby(axis=1, level=1).plot.scatter('means', 'diffs')
```

[image]

---

#### Loop over `groupby`

Get finer control

```
colors = iter('gr')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(6, 8))
for i, (k, d) in enumerate(df.groupby(axis=1, level=1)):
    d.xs(k, axis=1, level=1).plot.scatter(
        'means', 'diffs', title=k, ax=axes[i], c=next(colors))

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]